# Javascript set variable from within another function?

Tags: javascript

Say I have a variable called "true" in a function called "test." Then I have another function in a whole different script tag and I want to change "true" using my new function. How can I do this? Thanks.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var hello="no";
if(hello=="yes"){ 
  window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
  function confirmExit()
  {
    return "Message";
  }
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function show(id) {
     $('#' + id).show();
     var hello="yes";


}
</script>
```

It doesnt seem to be working...

Comment: It's all about scope. The variable must be defined with `var` at a higher scope than the functions that use it. Post your code and we can help. Without code, we cannot.

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle to demonstrate, `true` is a reserved word and can't be used for a variable name. It would be nice to see what you're doing.

Comment: `var true; function f1() {true = 'hi';} function f2() {true = "something else";}`

Comment: The variable is not actually named true, ill post code one second.

Comment: There, I posted the code

Comment: The `if` part executed already, so the changing `hello` won't make any effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your function, don't use the `var` keyword. Doing so declares a different variable `hello` in scope of the function.

```
// Earlier, you defined the variable at a higher scope here:
var hello="no";
// The function has *not* been called yet, so hello will never equal "yes" when this initially runs.
if(hello=="yes"){ 
  window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
  function confirmExit()
  {
    return "Message";
  }
}

function show(id) {
  $('#' + id).show();
  // No var here!
  // the variable was defined at a higher (window) scope already with the var keyword.
  hello="yes";
}
```

#### Update:

Your logic is faulty when calling the `onbeforeunload`. You are never binding the event unless `hello == "yes"`, which it never does when that runs.  Instead, check the variable contents in the `confirmExit()` function:

```
window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
function confirmExit()
{
  if (hello == "yes") {
    return "Message";
  }
}
```

Comment: @CJSculti Unless you called the function `show()`, the variable won't be set at the time it is initially called in the first script block.

Comment: I do call the function show. I call it onclick of a button. The point is so the box will only work after the button is pressed.

Comment: And the confirmExit function is called onunload of body, so that should be called last, no?

Answer (score 0):

```
// this will work in your case 
var hello="no";
if(hello=="yes"){
  window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
  function confirmExit()
  {
    return "Message";
  }
}
function show(id) {
     $('#' + id).show();
     hello="yes";
}


// Just an small explation of how scope works in Javascript

var hello = "no"; // this has a global scope.
function showGlobal(){
alert(hello); // will alert 'no'
}

function showLocal(){
 var hello ="yes"; // hello is now a local variable. Scope is limited to the function.
 alert(hello); // will alert 'yes'. Scope is local  

}

function showLocalBlock(){

    if(condition == 'true'){
    hello = 'yes';
    }
alert(hello); // will alert yes.

}

// Closure

function ShowClosure(){
 var hello = "yes";
    function ShowInner(){
    alert(hello); // here the variable hello takes the value of the function in which it was defined.

    }  
}
```